# Liferay with Struts2 getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed in event phase

Tags: struts, liferay

This is under JSP:

```
<%!
public PortletURL getActionURL(RenderResponse response, String action) {

    PortletURL portleturl = response.createRenderURL();

    try {
        portleturl.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE);
        portleturl.setParameter("struts_action", "helloForm");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return portleturl;
}
%>

<%

PortletURL helloFormssss = getActionURL(renderResponse, "helloForm");

System.out.println("The URL is helloFormssss " + helloFormssss);

%>
```

Passing this URL to jQuery AJAX:

```
function my_button_handler() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "helloFormssss",
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    });
}
```

This is my `Action` class

```
public class Struts2Action extends DefaultActionSupport {
    String name = null;

    public String getPOPChartData() throws Exception {
        // Enter business logic here

        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        String name = ParamUtil.getString(request, "namer");

        System.out.println("The name is " + name);

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.print("Hi");

        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

This is inside the `struts.xm`l file:

```
<action name="helloForm" class="com.robisoft.portlet.struts.action.Struts2Action" method="getPOPChartData">
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The URL is helloFormssss

```
http://localhost:8086/web/guest/home?p_p_id=HelloStruts_WAR_HelloStrutsportlet_INSTANCE_yip2vomViZSU&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_HelloStruts_WAR_HelloStrutsportlet_INSTANCE_yip2vomViZSU_struts_action=helloForm
```

This is the exception I am getting inside the server console

> 14:31:37,973 ERROR [Jsr168Dispatcher:38] Could not execute action.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed in event phase
>   at org.apache.struts2.portlet.servlet.PortletServletResponse.getWriter(PortletServletResponse.java:169)
>   at com.robisoft.portlet.struts.action.Struts2Action.getPOPChartData(Struts2Action.java:56)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.portlet.interceptor.PortletAwareInterceptor.intercept(PortletAwareInterceptor.java:88)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.portlet.interceptor.PortletStateInterceptor.intercept(PortletStateInterceptor.java:52)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>           at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>           at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.serviceAction(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:451)
>           at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.processAction(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:298)
>           at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:93)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Comment: I think, this may not be allowed: `writer.print("Hi"); return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;` that is to say writing to the response and then again calling a JSP to write to the response. It doesn't seem right, though I am only guessing here since I have not worked on Struts2, but this is how an `java.lang.IllegalStateException` is normally generated.  So I would suggest removing this line `writer.print("Hi");` and then running the code.